# How to update in DetailsView in asp.net web forms using entity framework 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have created a web form "Product.aspx" from where products are getting inserted in database.

I have used entity framework 4.0 and I am using DetailsView to insert data

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DV_Product" runat="server" Height="70px" Width="60%" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="ProductId" DataSourceID="EDS_Product" 
    DefaultMode="Insert" OnItemInserting="DVProduct_ItemInserting">
    <Fields>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Product1" HeaderText="Product" SortExpression="Product1" ControlStyle-Width="250"/>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EDS_Category" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=SpunkKraftEntities1" 
                    DefaultContainerName="SpunkKraftEntities1" EnableDelete="True" 
                    EnableFlattening="False"  EntitySetName="Categories" EntityTypeFilter="Category">
                </asp:EntityDataSource>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DD_Category" runat="server" DataSourceID="EDS_Category" Width="250"
                    DataTextField="Category1" DataValueField="CategoryId" OnInit="DD_Category_Init">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" >
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Description" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" OnInit="txt_Description_Init" Width="250">
                </asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Unit Price" HeaderText="Unit Price"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Upload Image">
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fu_image" runat="server" OnInit="fu_image_Init"/>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="true" />                        

    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

[image]

I have another page "ManageProduct.aspx" where I have used gridview to display list of products

[image]

I want to edit records in DetailsView. What I can imagine is when I click on "Select" or "Edit" then it should redirect to the "Product.aspx?ProductId=x" and fill the product details in DetailsView. What I want to ask is how can I redirect with the product Id and once redirected to "Product.aspx" how could I fill the details and update ?

Comment: What's your question here ?. You are asking for how to update the product ? or You want to redirect the page on click of select in grid view ?

Comment: What I want to ask is how can I redirect with the product Id and once redirected to "Product.aspx" how could I fill the details and update ?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way,and here am considering your Product Id as Product Name.

On RowEditing event, do like this

```
Response.Redirect("Products.aspx?Id="+GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
```

On page_load of Products.aspx mention like this,

```
if(Request[Id]!=null)
{
    string demo = Request[Id].ToString();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Your connection String");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Your table where name = '"+demo+"'")
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(dr.Read())
    {
       DetailsView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text = dr.GetString(0);//Your Product goes here
       // Proceed the same for your remaining entries 
    }
}
```

Hope you might got some ideas to go further. In case of any confusion from my answer. Please let me know.

Comment: @Shekhar Dalvi let me know the output.